# Clock_t returns big negative numbers

Tags: performance, time, clock

I am trying to measure the running time in nanoseconds of a function by using `clock()` function, like this:

```
clock_t start_t = clock();  
random_function();  
clock_t end_t = clock();
printf("Elapsed time: %f\n", (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

When I run the program I **sometimes** get very big negative numbers as a result.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Perhaps because of 32-bit wraparound?

Comment: This would mean that it's not advisable to use this function (clock()) to measure the time at all, since it gives random results?

Comment: It's not random, it just has finite range.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But it still gives negative results sometimes, so it troubles the execution of the program.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to see values of start_t and end_t when this happens?

Comment: Yes, I printed their values and were also big negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If your platform us using unsigned for clock_t you can use modulo `std::numeric_limits<clock_t>::max()` subtraction, instead of the absolute one

Comment: you can use unsigned -1